# Clearing Values in Column 1 when Column 2 is empty

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("DC3:DC22").Select
Selection.Replace What:="W", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
If Range("DC3").Value = "" Then
Range("DB3").ClearContents
End If
If Range("DC4").Value = "" Then
Range("DB4").ClearContents
End If
If Range("DC5").Value = "" Then
Range("DB5").ClearContents
End If
If Range("DC6").Value = "" Then
Range("DB6").ClearContents
.... etc.
```

How do I make this VBA macro more efficient so that all values in range (DB3:DB22) are cleared if their adjacent cell in (DC3:DC22) is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out - you can loop over the cells in DC3:DC22 and clear the cells to the left as needed.

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("DC3:DC22") 'or some other specific sheet...
    
    rng.Replace What:="W", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

    'loop and clear cell to left as needed
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then c.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
    Next c

End Sub
```